# Finding unpaired element in an array

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

So I have just started self learning algorithms by working through some sample questions I found (where you can check your solution's correctness and time complexity), and am a little confused by one question in particular.

In this question, I am given an array with an odd number of integer elements, where each element of the array can be paired with another element that has the same value, except for one element that is left unpaired. The question is asking me to find this unpaired element. The function I tried using is below in python;

```py
def solution(A):
    
    N = len(A)   # constant
    if N == 1:   # constant
        return A[0]

    mergesort(A)   # NlogN

    if A[-1] != A[-2]:  # constant
        return A[-1]

    for i in range(0,N-1,2):   # apparently not linear?
        if A[i] != A[i+1]:
            return A[i]
```

Why this is `O(N^2)`, rather than `O(NlogN)`?

The only reason I can think of is that the comparison of `A[i]` and `A[i+1]` is itself `O(N)`, but I don't see why it wouldn't be constant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks heaps for reading!

Comment: Why do you think that it is quadratic?

Comment: The `for` loop is linear. The comparisons are O(1)

Comment: It would be quadratic if you didn't sort the array and had to search for the paired element.

Comment: ok good, I thought I was going crazy. I am doing this question on the website codility and it was showing the following outcome from testing my answer 
https://ibb.co/x7Xt9hH

Comment: I think you're supposed to use a `O(N)` solution, might be why your `O(NlgN)` solution isn't accepted

Comment: ah right ok, that  seems reasonable. Still seems strange it tells me it is O(N**2) though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Abhinav Mathur stated in the comments, it's likely that that your algorithm needs to be linear, rather than `O(n log n)`.

Here's a solution that runs in linear time that leverages the XOR operation and the following properties of the operation:

- XOR is commutative. That is, `x ^ y = y ^ x`.
- Any number XOR'd with itself is `0`. That is `x ^ x = 0`.
- Any number XOR'd with `0` is itself. That is, `x ^ 0 = x`.

If we XOR all the numbers together, all of the numbers that appear twice will produce 0 in our XOR result. Whenever we XOR a zero value with the number that only appears once, we get the number that only appears once.

So, our answer is the result of XORing all the numbers in the array together:

```py
def solution(A):
    result = 0
    for item in A:
        result ^= item
    return result
```

or if you like one-liners, use `functools.reduce()`:

```py
from functools import reduce
from operator import xor

def solution(A):
    return reduce(xor, A)
```

If we assume that the XOR operation takes constant time, then this algorithm runs in linear time.

You could also solve this using a hashset or `collections.Counter()`, but those will use a linear amount of memory. This approach uses constant memory.

Comment: Ah ok cool, that is very neat indeed. Just to confirm I understand this correctly, is the idea that all the pairs will eventually collapse into 0's (because XOR is commutative), so eventually all you will be left with is 0 XOR the unpaired element, which equals the unpaired element?

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct. Commutativity allows you to rearrange the expression into one where you can pair up equivalent values and cancel them out as zeroes. This eventually would give you something like `0 ^ 0 ^ 0 ^ ... ^ n`, where `n` is the value that is the odd one out.

Comment: How about `return reduce(xor, A)`?

Comment: Good catch, I'll edit that in later today.